# Android Alarm Manager API

Tags: android, performance

I had been tasked with developing an alarm app. Something simple which lets users set an alarm at a specific time and select a music file that should play when the alarm goes off. The app works great on phone like Samsung, Motorola, and Nexus but on Xiomi, Oppo, Vivo phones the alarm does not go off at the correct times and sometimes it does not fire at all. I have used Android's AlarmManager APIs. I am wondering if there is something else I need to do to get the alarm to work as expected on devices like xiomi, oppo, and vivo. Most of the solutions on StackOverflow have not worked out for me. If there are devs here in this subreddit who have worked with AlarmManager APIs before or worked on Apps with Alarm features, id really appreciates some more insight into AlarmManager APIs and why they don't work as expected across all phones and if there are any alternatives I should be using.

Comment: add your code how you setting the Alarm ,

Answer (score 0):

Bellow is the method which will help you, Which I tested with the different-different device it's working.

```
/**
     * Method for start Alarm on Defined time
     *
     * @param context
     */
    public static void startAlarm(Context context,int minutes) {
        Logger.print("AlarmReceiver startAlarm  called");
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, WakefulBrodcastReceiverService.class);
        alarmIntent.setAction("testAPP");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123451, alarmIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        long alarmPeriodicTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + Utils.getTimeInMilliSec(Constant.TimeType.MINUTE, minutes);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmPeriodicTime, pendingIntent);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmPeriodicTime, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmPeriodicTime, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```