# Alarm manager not starting service as expected after API 23

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, backgroundworker

Recently i have upgraded my project to 26 Api level. after that alarm manager is not working for me. I don't know what's the problem but i guess the alarm is not at all working, whenever app is in background for all device above lolipop(>=M). i have gone through other questions and and have followed some suggestion like 'WakefulBroadcastReceiver',

Below is my code and flow of the same

### Scenario

**- setting a repeative alarm for every 15 minutes.**

```
     Intent dil = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationSyncTaskReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent dlpi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 225566, dil, 0);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            lFreq = 15;

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>23)
            am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,(System.currentTimeMillis()+5 * 60 * 1000L),dlpi);
        else
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 5 * 60 * 1000L, lFreq * 60 * 1000L, dlpi);
```

**- which is invoking a 'WakefulBroadcastReceiver'.**

```
  public class LocationSyncTaskReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = LocationSyncTaskReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    WakefulIntentService.acquireStaticLock(context);
    Intent locationSync = new Intent(context, SyncLocationTracker.class);
    startWakefulService(context,locationSync);
}
```

}

**- above code is calling 'WakefulIntentService' - SyncLocationTracker**

```
    @Override
public void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
    userService = UserServiceImpl.getInstance();
    Log.d(TAG, "Data Tracker : doWakefulWork called");
    if (userService.getLoggedInUser() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "User is logged in so continuing sync ....");
        WakefulIntentService.acquireStaticLock(getApplicationContext());
        syncService = DataSyncServiceImpl.getInstance();
        syncService.syncLocation();
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "User is not logged in so discarding sync ....");
        stopSelf();
    }
    stopSelf();
}
```

**- 'syncService.syncLocation();' is finally doing a some calculation and multiple network request**

Comment: Hi Uday this is my answer which may help you to start alarm  properly https://stackoverflow.com/a/49042254/3894930

Comment: @DhavalSolanki its working for below 23 but not above 23 and i am using setExactAndAllowWhileIdle still its not working

Comment: Google changed the behavior and introduced "Doze" in API level 23. API level 24 has even more restrictions. See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#perf

Comment: Yes I know, But system will normal alarm, You can read below link   with section Doze restrictions 
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Comment: If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it using this library
[Evernote job scheduler library](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)

It uses `JobScheduler`, `GcmNetworkManager` or `AlarmManager` depending on your android os version.

All features from Android Oreo are backward compatible back to Ice Cream Sandwich.

The `JobRequest.Builder` class has many extra options, e.g. you can specify a required network connection, make the job periodic, pass some extras with a bundle, restore the job after a reboot or run the job at an exact time.

Example

```
     int jobId = new JobRequest.Builder(DemoSyncJob.TAG)
        .setExecutionWindow(30_000L, 40_000L)
        .setBackoffCriteria(5_000L, JobRequest.BackoffPolicy.EXPONENTIAL)
        .setRequiresCharging(true)
        .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
        .setRequiredNetworkType(JobRequest.NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .setExtras(extras)
        .setRequirementsEnforced(true)
        .setUpdateCurrent(true)
        .build()
        .schedule();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your if condition from:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23)
```

to:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
```