# The alarm is not created

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am trying to create an alarm using AlarmManager but the following code don't create alarm:

```
public static void scheduleAlarm(Context context, int requestCode , 
                                       int days , int hour , int minute ) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK , days);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR , hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND , 0);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pi);

}
```

Comment: did you try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49856645/3678308        ?

Comment: How exactly are you determining that "the following code don't create alarm"?

Comment: I don't see a Log/Toast message

Comment: Are you sure the `Calendar` is being set to the correct date/time? Which "Log/Toast message" do you mean? Are those in your `AlarmReceiver`? Do you have a `<receiver>` element in the manifest for that?

Comment: Yes I got an `<receiver>` tag in the manifest and the Log/Toast in the receiver

Answer (score 0):

Might be because of two problems

> 1- setRepeating() is inexact on Android 4.4+ with an
>   android:targetSdkVersion of 19 or higher.
>
> 2- You are not using WakefulBroadcastReceiver, my
>   WakefulIntentService, or your own WakeLock, and so the device can fall
>   back asleep between the time the alarm is triggered any by the time
>   your service completes its work.

Comment: I changed the minSdkVersion to 19 in the build gradle.
this is my receiver:
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context , "scheduleAlarm" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

Answer (score 0):

try to use this instead

```
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pi)
```